# Why Swift prints multidimensional array with only one for loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the following code in Swift:

```
var array: [[Int]] = [[6,8,1],
                      [3,3,3],
                      [2,1,2]];

for (var x=0;x<array.count;x++){
       print (array[x]);
   }
}
```

The result is:

```
6,8,1
3,3,3
2,1,2
```

Why Swift prints a multidimensional array with 1 for loop. And how i can 
row and column if I have no second for loop ?

Comment: please add more inputs to your question. your question is not clear

Comment: It just print the element inside first array

Comment: What is the expected output, just printing every number?

Comment: Be amazed, I could print the array without _any_ loops `print(array)`

Comment: I expected to see some memory addresses when i run the code like that and to print the actual values only after adding a nested for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are printing the array for each iteration, in your case **array[x]** is an **Array** itself

it is the same as `print([6,8,1])`

Answer (score 1):

You have to access it every row and every column

```
for var i = 0 ; i < array.count; i++ {
    for var j = 0; j < array[i].count; j++ {
         print(array[i][j])
      }
}
i - Row
j - Column
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array` type adopts [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html) protocol that is used by `print` function.  The implementation is such that it lists all elements in the array separated by commas.  For each element in the array its implementation of the same protocol will be used.  That's why you can print it the way you do, and actually you can even print just the `array`, and even more than that:

```
let array1 = [0, 1]
let array2 = [array1, array1]
let array3 = [array2, array2]
let array4 = [array3, array3]

print(array1) // [0, 1]
print(array2) // [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
print(array3) // [[[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]]]
print(array4) // [[[[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]]], [[[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

X was incremented till array.count

Your array is an array containing arrays. Hence it printed 1st, followed by 2nd, 3rd row.

Comment: How can i then access elements by row and column like matrix , while I am iterating the array ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var store: [[Int]] = [
    [6, 8, 1],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [2, 1, 2, 4],
    []
]
// returns optional value, if you pass wrong indexes, returns nil 
func getValue<T>(store:[[T]], row: Int, column: Int)->T? {
    // check valid indexes
    guard row >= 0 && column >= 0 else { return nil }
    guard row < store.count else { return nil }
    guard column < store[row].count else { return nil }

    return store[row][column]
}

let v31 = getValue(store, row: 3, column: 0) // nil
let v21 = getValue(store, row: 2, column: 1) // 1
let v01 = getValue(store, row: 0, column: 1) // 8
let v23 = getValue(store, row: 2, column: 3) // 4

let store2 = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
let u11 = getValue(store2, row: 1, column: 1)

let store3:[[Any]] = [[1, 2, "a"],[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]]
let x02 = getValue(store3, row: 0, column: 2) // "a"
let x11 = getValue(store3, row: 1, column: 1) // 2.2
```